# How to store string via double quotation?

Tags: c#

I need to store value like

```
string stringValue = {"E":false,"T":1,"I":[],"M":"","S":false,"ST":1};
```

in string.

I have a value given as above and i want to store this value in a single string.
Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape double quote by back slash, you can find more about escaping string [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
string stringValue = "{\"E\":false,\"T\":1,\"I\":[],\"M\":\"\",\"S\":false,\"ST\":1}";
```

> A character that follows a backslash character () in a
>   regular-string-literal-character must be one of the following
>   characters: ', ", \, 0, a, b, f, n, r, t, u, U, x, v. Otherwise, a
>   compile-time error occurs, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to store is actually [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

You can easily store it into a string by serializing it first:

For this you can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class that is part of `System.Web.Script.Serialization`

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

...

string stringValue = JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(YourJsonObject);
//YourJsonObject here would be the object you are getting the value from.
```

You can then later reverse the process by deserializing it back to an object:

```
var myJsonObj = JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(stringValue);
```

Note: The class is  part of the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly.